# Cannot Bind Argument to Parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, rename-item-cmdlet

```
Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\.txt','.log' }
```

I have 3 text files in my current path, I'm using this snip bit of code found in the last example of...

```
get-help rename-item -full
```

(Powershell Version 2.0). For whatever reason, I keep receiving the following error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:40
+ Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName { $_.name -replace 
'\.txt','.log' }
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (testfile3.txt:PSObject) [Rename-Item], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Rena
meItemCommand
```

Clearly my alteration form .txt to .log isn't an empty string, and this matches exactly the same code as in found in Microsoft's last example of the cmdlet rename-item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either don't use the `-Name` parameter since that outputs just strings containing the full path or don't reference the `Name` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_ -replace '\.txt','.log' }
```

Comment: Thanks, still a question, how do I figure out that the Name property outputs the file only as a string?

Comment: You can look at the help `man Get-ChildItem -Parameter Name` or pipe the output through Get-Member e.g. `Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt | Get-Member`.